# Error al obtener el valor de un autocomplete Material UI react

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Tengo un formulario que necesito enviar por un metodo post, el problema es cuando quiero obtner el valor de un autocomplete en el metodo handleChange.
[Aqui](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-autocomplete-forked-mpwrf?file=/src/index.js) mi código

Este es el resultado que obtengo:
Y no entiendo porque se crea una cuarta propiedad undefined.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ese error pasa porque no estás capturando bien los datos del `<Autocomplete />`

La manera correcta de hacerlo se explica en esta pregunta: [Getting the value in the React material-UI Autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58666189/getting-the-value-in-the-react-material-ui-autocomplete)

Ahí se muestra que hay que pasar como parámetro a la función del `onChange` los valores `(event, value)`.

Y pone el siguiente ejemplo:

```
<Autocomplete
  onChange={(event, value) => console.log(value)} // prints the selected value
  renderInput={params => (
    <TextField {...params} label="Label" variant="outlined" fullWidth />
  )}
/>
```

En tu caso podrías implementar esta solución agregando una nueva función para manejar los datos del `<Autocomplete />` y los otros `TextField` por separado.

Por ejemplo, la función `handleChange` que ya está creada la dejarías tal cual y además de esa crearías una nueva función llamada `handleChangeAutocomplete` así:

```
const handleChangeAutocomplete = (event, value, name) => {
console.log(value.idTipo);
setEncuesta((prevState) => ({
  ...prevState,
  [name]: value.idTipo
}));
console.log(encuesta);
};
```

Y la llamarías en el `onChange` de la siguiente manera:

```
<Autocomplete
    name="idTipo"
    options={tipos}
    getOptionLabel={(option) => option.descripcion || ""}
    defaultValue={[tipos[0]]}
    onChange={(event, value) =>
        handleChangeAutocomplete(event, value, "idTipo")
    }
    renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField
        {...params}
        variant="standard"
        placeholder="Tipo"
        margin="normal"
        fullWidth
        />
    )}
/>
```

Comment: Ok pero sigo obteniendo NaN para idTipo

Comment: Ahora edito mi respuesta para darte una solución más completa y se entienda mejor lo que quiero decir.